# Solar maximum and minimum

Tags: the-sun

What are solar maximum and solar minimum?
Is there a relation between sun spots and solar maximum and minimum?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Solar maximum**
*Solar maximum or solar max is a normal period of greatest solar activity in the 11 year solar cycle of the Sun. During solar maximum, large numbers of sunspots appear and the sun's irradiance output grows by about 0.07%.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_maximum) The increased energy output of solar maxima can impact Earth's global climate and recent studies have shown some correlation with regional weather patterns.* [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_maximum)

**Solar minimum**
*Solar minimum is the period of least solar activity in the 11 year solar cycle of the sun. During this time, sunspot and solar flare activity diminishes, and often does not occur for days at a time. The date of the minimum is described by a smoothed average over 12 months of sunspot activity, so identifying the date of the solar minimum usually can only happen 6 months after the minimum takes place. Solar minima are not generally correlated with changes in climate but recent studies have shown a correlation with regional weather patterns.* [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_minimum)